# Laravel 8 - 2 database connection - leftjoin

Tags: database, laravel, model, controller, left-join

I've got 2 different databases and need a leftjoin to the second one.
It's on Laravel 8. It's a MariaDB and the sql_erp it's on MSSQL.

Who can help me?

My received fault-message is:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sql_erp.artikel_stamm' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `aa_bom` left join `sql_erp`.`ARTIKEL_STAMM` on `bom`.`art_nr` = `Artikel_Stamm`.`ARTNR` where `_x_zu_aa_doc_steps` = 1 order by `pos` asc limit 99)
```

in my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Arbeitsanw\aa_doc_steps;
use App\Models\Arbeitsanw\aa_doc_header;
use App\Models\Arbeitsanw\aa_bom;
use App\Models\Arbeitsanw\ERP\Artikel_Stamm;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;    

    public function loadstep($id)
    {
        $aa_doc_steps = aa_doc_steps::find($id);

        //Stkl laden
        $aa_doc_step_id=$id;
        $aa_stkl_artikels = aa_bom::where('_x_zu_aa_doc_steps', '=', $aa_doc_step_id)
                                        ->leftJoin('sql_erp.ARTIKEL_STAMM', 'bom.art_nr', '=', 'Artikel_Stamm.ARTNR')       
                                        ->orderBy('pos', 'asc')
                                        ->take(99)
                                        ->get();


        
        return view('aa_edit_arbeitsschritt', compact('aa_doc_steps', 'aa_stkl_artikels'));
    }
```

my model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Arbeitsanw\ERP;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Http\Controllers\aa_stkl_form_controller;

class Artikel_Stamm extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $connection = 'sql_erp';
    protected $table = 'ARTIKEL_STAMM';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Laravel Eloquent Left join structure as an example

```
$ c = Customer :: leftJoin ('orders', function ($ join) (
      $ join-> on ('customers.id', '=', 'orders.customer_id');
    })
    -> whereNull ('orders.customer_id')
    -> first ();
```

You can look at this code structure. Also, you need to define `$ fillable = ['table_column', 'table_column']` in the Model file.